# IIS App Domain or App pool recycle

Tags: iis

My call center application users won't close the browser at end of their day instead leave the browser as such, next day they start using the application on the same browser from where they left. During midnight if any deployment or app pool recycles happens they application throws exception and user are forced to close the browser & open brand new one to proceed with using the application.On new browser application behaves with the complaint but why not on the browser they used last day.

We are using IIS 10 & MVC 5, during deployment VS precompiled options are used to merge all outputs to the single assembly.

Any idea please why MVC application throws the exception after IIS App Domain or App pool recycle on the old/already opened browser & behaves normally once when application launched on new browser??

Comment: Long live sessions are rarely considered a feature. You probably should use JavaScript at client side to show a session timeout and force a client side refresh. It has little to do with IIS.